# photo libraryからのassetの削除について

Tags: swift

Swiftを独学で勉強中の初心者です。photo libraryからのassetの削除について、Appleのサイトからサンプルコードを見つけたのですが、}, completionHandler: completion)の所で、
completionに「未解決の識別子の使用」のエラーが出ます。どの様に修正したら良いのでしょうか。諸先輩の皆様、よろしくご教示お願いいたします。

```
if assetCollection != nil {
        // Remove the asset from the selected album.
        PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
            let request = PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest(for: self.assetCollection)!
            request.removeAssets([self.asset] as NSArray)
         }, completionHandler: completion)
    } else {
        // Delete the asset from the photo library.
        PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
            PHAssetChangeRequest.deleteAssets([self.asset] as NSArray)
        }, completionHandler: completion)
    }
```

Comment: あなたのコードの中で`completion`をどこでどのように定義しているのでしょう? どこにも定義していなければ当然 _「未解決の識別子の使用」のエラー_ になります。 **コードの断片だけでなく関連するコード全体を示す**、**「Appleのサイトからサンプルコード」を取ってきたのならそのリンクを示す**、など、関連情報を適切にご質問に含んでいただくと、適切で分かりやすい回答をより早く得られることになるでしょう。ご自身の質問は「編集」で内容を修正できますので、回答に必要な情報を適宜追記するようにしてください。

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。Appleのリンクは(https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/browsing_and_modifying_photo_albums) です。completionHandler含め、自身、クロージャの事はまだよく理解できておりません。ご指導よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: リンクのご提示ありがとうございます。ただし、そのような極めて重要な情報はご質問を編集して本文に追記された方が、より多くの人に目に留まるので、より多くの人に問題点を考えてもらえることにつながります。私がダウンロードしたサンプルコードでは該当部分と思われる場所にちゃんと`completion`の定義があります。一度書いていますが、コードの断片だけ示されてもどこをどう直すべきと言うことは示せません。何千行にもなるので無い限り、クラス全体、メソッド全体を示すようにしてください。

Comment: サンプルコードはダウンロードせず、サイトの当該部分だけ見ていました。ダウンロードサンプルには、確かにcompletionの定義が有りました。ありがとうございました。クラス等はまだ作成途中で、初心者のため恥ずかしくてお見せできませんです。まだまだ勉強が足りないです。何度もお時間をとらせて申し訳ないです。本当にありがとうございました。

Comment: 「初心者のため恥ずかしくてお見せできませんです」…そんなことを言っていたら、「独学で勉強」でまともなアプリが作れる程度まで技術を習得するのに、気が遠くなるような時間がかかってしまいますよ。自分で書いたコードをうまく動かない部分まで含めて色々な人に見てもらう、プログラミング習得の近道です。今後何十年もかけて学習していければ良い、と言うので無い限り、積極的に自身のコードを晒すのを強く強く強烈に強くお勧めしておきます。なお、ダウンロードした部分を見ても、まだうまくいかない場合は、このご質問を修正して質問されれば良いと思いますが、その際には関連するコードを全部質問中に含めると言うのをお忘れなく。